# SQL query runs forever when using a column instead of a string constant in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I want to generate date ranges from whatever the max date in `CustomersHub` is to some other date say, `'2022-11-16'`.

Using a scalar column in where clause causes the query to seemingly run forever. I checked my stop condition to make sure query doesn't run infinitely and to test I put in a constant value that was basically the same as what my table column had. And the query started to work fine.

Here are the two tables:

```
create table #Temp
(
    dt DateTime,
);


create table CustomersHub
(
    id int,
    firstloadedDate DateTime,
);
```

This is how I'm inserting data into the temp table:

```
insert into #Temp
select top 1 hub.firstloadedDate max_date from CustomersHub hub order by max_date desc;
```

And finally the query to generate date ranges:

```
WITH e00(n)
     AS (SELECT 1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1),
     e02(n)
     AS (SELECT 1
         FROM   [e00] [a],
                [e00] [b]),
     e04(n)
     AS (SELECT 1
         FROM   [e02] [a],
                [e02] [b]),
     e08(n)
     AS (SELECT 1
         FROM   [e04] [a],
                [e04] [b]),
     e16(n)
     AS (SELECT 1
         FROM   [e08] [a],
                [e08] [b]),
     e32(n)
     AS (SELECT 1
         FROM   [e16] [a],
                [e16] [b]),
     num_tally(n)
     AS (SELECT Row_number()
                  OVER (
                    ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL) )
         FROM   [e32]),
     tally
     AS (SELECT Dateadd(day, n - 1, dt) dates,
                n,
                dt
         FROM   [num_tally],
                #temp
         WHERE  Datediff(day, dt, '2022-11-16') >= n)
SELECT *
FROM   tally

DROP TABLE #temp
```

In the `tally` cte, if I replace `dt` with some date like `'2022-10-20'` then it works otherwise it just keeps running & running.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Larnu updated my question at the top to clarify.

Comment: For performance questions, please provide your actual execution plan by uploading it to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) and linking it in your Post.

Answer (score 1):

I would, instead, generate a Tally with enough numbers, and *then* just use `DATEADD`:

```sql
DECLARE @FromDate date,
        @ToDate date;

SELECT @FromDate = MAX(hub.firstloadedDate),
       @ToDate = '20221116'
FROM dbo.CustomersHub;

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS (
    SELECT 0 AS I
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY,@FromDate,@ToDate))
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4) --Up to 10,000 rows
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I, @FromDate) AS Dt
FROM Tally T;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JIJc3f80)

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. However, I wanted to avoid calculating `top` as it isn't really supported in oracle in case, I wanted to port this query over there. I'm more of looking for an understanding as to why it's taking so much time when I'm using a column in the `where` clause.

Comment: Your question is about SQL Server, not Oracle, @MuhammadTaha . Use the tools at your disposal for the product you are using. If you need to an Oracle solution in the future, write a different version for Oracle when you need it.